# Java collection Framewok Map Output Problem

Tags: java

```
    String A="A";
    String B="A";
    String C= new String("A");
    Map m1=new HashMap<String,String>();
    m1.put(A,"A");
    m1.put(B,"A");
    m1.put(C,"A");
    System.out.println(m1.size());
```

Why the map size is 1 can anyone explain the working and also explain how map size is 1???

Comment: Because `equals()` and `hashcode()` return the same value for your three keys, so they are considered the same key (and a map doesn't allow duplicate keys) .

Comment: because you are using the same key for the three values

Comment: As @Arnaud said, the 3 keys used are all identical as far as the HashMap is concerned. HashMap does not care if the keys are derived from the same variable, it cares about the outputs of key.equals() and key.hashcode().

Comment: Check out the following article if you want to manage Map with "duplicate" keys: https://www.baeldung.com/java-map-duplicate-keys

Comment: @Arnaud what happen if equals method return same value but hashcode is diffrent or vice versa?????

Comment: The contract of both methods is to have consistently to avoid weird things, see https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts and the javadoc : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys of a `Map` have to be unique.

So by doing `m1.put(B, "anything");`, since `B = "A"` you are replacing the previous value associated with the key `"A"`. Keys are checked by the `equals()` method, and if the implementation is a `HashMap` it will look up the keys by `hashcode()` first, before confirming equivalence.

Also something to note, unrelated to `Map` as such. Java tries to de-duplicate strings that contain the same thing (since a `String` is immutable it can safely do it). So it is likely that `String A = "A"` and `String B = "A"` will actually also point to the same object (although this is JVM dependent).

`String C = new String("A");` will force it to create a new `String` object, athough latest garbage collectors will [deduplicate](http://java-performance.info/java-string-deduplication/) this too, and although it will be a different wrapper object, the buffer inside will be replaced so that it is the same as the others.

Answer (score 0):

Java String is immutable and the behaviour of the string cannot be changed. Each time when you make any changes, it creates the new String than updating the value. So, here the value "A" is same for all String objects and the hashcode also the same for all three objects. All three values in hashmap pointing to the same hashcode.